# Jetpack compose Justified and RTL Text

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In jetpack Compose, you can Justify a `Text` like this:

```kotlin
Text(
       text = text,
       textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
    )
```

If you want support RTL, you achive this by:

```kotlin
Text(
       text = text,
       textAlign = TextAlign.Right
    )
```

How can a `Text()` support RTL text and justify it same time in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After several hour testing, I reach this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun JustifiedRTLText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
            modifier = modifier,
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Jetpack Compose RTL or LTR will automatically set by according to the text content. But we can force it by changing the `textDirection` of `style` to `TextDirection.Content` or `TextDirection.RTL`

```kotlin
Text(
    text = text,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
    style = TextStyle(textDirection = TextDirection.Content)
)
```

Comment: I think this is cleaner than using `CompositionLocal` which is designed for something else entirely.

Comment: It will remove all styles applied to the Text

Answer (score 0):

to prevent removing other styles applied to the Text, you can do it as below:

```
Text(
    text = "سلام اندروید!",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl)
)
```